# Building tree hierarchy using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on creating a tree hierarchy using Linq and since I am new to it I am facing the trouble. I have two tables from which I have to create the hierarchy and the table is as follows

**Table A**

```
Id
Name
Description
```

**Table B**

```
Id of A (as foreign key)
Name
```

And I need the structure like this:

```
name(From table A)
     |_name(from table B)
     |_name (from table B)
name(from table A)
```

I have a class defined as

```
  Public Class C
   {
        public class C(C item,IEnumerable<C> id,IEnumerable<C> data)
            {

              AId=item.AI;
              BId=item.BId;
               AName=item.Name;
              Childeren=id;
            }

           public IEnumerable<C> Children{get;set}
         }
```

All the name of tables must be displayed even it does not have nodes

I used Group join to get data from  both the tables and now I am having problem with code to select the node and its sub node. My linq code is as follows:

```
private List<Model> BuildHierarchy(IEnumerable<Model> Hirs)
{
    var families=Hirs.ToLookup(x => x.AId);
    var topmost = families.First().Select(s => s);
    Func<string, IList<Model>> children = null;
    children = (parentId) => families[parentId]
                    .OrderBy(x => x.BId)
                    .Select(x => new Model(x, children(x.BId), Hirs))
                    .OrderBy(o=> o.Bid).ToList();

    return topmost.Select(mod => new Model(mod, children(mod.BId), Hirs)).ToList();
}
```

What it does is it only gets the first node of Table A but node all the data. When I click on the node the method gets invoked again creating same node.

I have no idea why I am having this problem if you guys would help me this would be a great help as I am stuck in here for long period of time.

Thank you

Comment: What is `Model`? Show where you call `BuildHierarchy`?

Comment: Model is to hold data where data from database is hold. BuildHierarchy is called after model is populated and above code is supposed to create node and its sub note

Comment: This was a call to add code to your post. It is not clear how you call `BuildHierarchy` and where the output goes. Also, where are class `A` and `B` in your code?

Comment: A and B are the representaion of database defined in my code.Build hierarchy is called when data from A and B is obtained and it returns value to the class where nodes are created. i having trouble in itereation of data as it returns only one set of data ie first row of data of database

Comment: Boy! It only gets worse. Suddenly new mystery class pops up and still no one but you knows how `Model` and `A` and `B` (and now `C`) are connected. I give up.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I'll make edits and make it cleaner or more precise.

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    DataTable dtPrimary = new DataTable();
    dtPrimary.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    dtPrimary.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));


    DataTable dtForeign = new DataTable();
    dtForeign.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    dtForeign.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));

    ds.Tables.Add(dtPrimary);
    ds.Tables.Add(dtForeign);
    DataRelation dr = new DataRelation("myRelation", dtPrimary.Columns["Id"], dtForeign.Columns["Id"]);

    dtPrimary.Rows.Add(1, "Name1");
    dtPrimary.Rows.Add(2, "Name2");

    dtForeign.Rows.Add(1,"Child1OfName1");
    dtForeign.Rows.Add(1, "Child2OfName1");
    dtForeign.Rows.Add(2, "ChildOfName2");

    DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();
    dtNew.Columns.Add("Id");
    dtNew.Columns.Add("Name");

var items =
    from row in dtPrimary.AsEnumerable()
    let foreignRow = (
    from innerRow in dtForeign.AsEnumerable()
    where innerRow.Field<int>("Id") == row.Field<int>("Id")
    select innerRow)
    select new { Parent = row.Field<string>("Name"), Children = foreignRow };
```